# Javascript homework

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var images1 = new Array("strawberry.jpg", "apple.jpg", "cherry.jpg", "orange.jpg", "pear.jpg");
      var images2 = new Array("strawberry.jpg", "apple.jpg", "cherry.jpg", "orange.jpg", "pear.jpg");
      var images3 = new Array("strawberry.jpg", "apple.jpg", "cherry.jpg", "orange.jpg", "pear.jpg");
      var length = images1.length;
      var randImg = Math.round(Math.random() * (length - 1));
      document.write('<img src="' + images1[randImg] + '" >');
      var length = images2.length;
      var randImg = Math.round(Math.random() * (length - 1));
      document.write('<img src="' + images2[randImg] + '" >');
      var length = images3.length;
      var randImg = Math.round(Math.random() * (length - 1));
      document.write('<img src="' + images3[randImg] + '" >');

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

I want to compare the images of the arrays if 3 images are strawberry I want to create an alert message like 'congrats you won' but I couldn't do that, how can I do that ?

Comment: You're overwriting `randImg` twice. Is this on purpose?

Comment: dont reuse the same variable name and try using objects/functions when you repeat the same concept/code

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var images = ["strawberry.jpg", "apple.jpg", "cherry.jpg", "orange.jpg", "pear.jpg"];
      var length = images.length;
      var randImg1 = Math.round(Math.random() * (length - 1));
      document.write('<img src="' + images[randImg1] + '" >');
      var randImg2 = Math.round(Math.random() * (length - 1));
      document.write('<img src="' + images[randImg2] + '" >');
      var randImg3 = Math.round(Math.random() * (length - 1));
      document.write('<img src="' + images[randImg3] + '" >');

      if (randImg1 == randImg2 && randImg2 == randImg3 && randImg3 == "strawberry.jpg") {
          // You won!
      }

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Note how I removed the redundant `images1`, `2`, and `3` and replaced them with a single array, `images`. I also removed the constructor, and did the same thing for `length1`, `2`, and `3`.

However, the key part is how I defined 3 random variables, `randImg1`, `2`, and `3`. Then you can compare them all later.